# Does the Cloud solve the hosting location dilemma?

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting

My startup is located in Europe where most of our current users are.

I'm looking for a host that will allow us to scale to the US and Asia without latency taking its toll on performance.

Does the cloud solve the distance = latency problem?

If not, Where would be the ideal hosting location for a growing startup?

Some data:
Asp.net 3.5
SQL 2005
Jquery (lots of Ajax)
MVC

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud is just an abstraction.  It doesn't affect the underlying physical nature of the servers running your code and hosting your data.  If the systems storing your data are a long way from your users there will some latency, no matter how you access them.

Most Cloud providers allow you to choose where you want your data - for example, [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) lets you choose to store your data in either the US or Europe - but no provider is going to be able to magically store all your data in multiple locations simultaneously.

If you want the benefit of multiple data centres you'd have to allow simultaneous updates at each location and there is no way to synchronise such updates without knowledge of the business logic of the application, so you're going to have to write some code to do this.

You're still going to have a look at what each Cloud provider offers and work out how each can help solve your problems, but you're going to have to do some work yourself.

Comment: @Dave, fastest typist wins.  I'll delete my almost duplicate answer.

Comment: @Glen - that's very good of you.  I'll go and find an answer of yours I like and upvote it.

Comment: I was looking into Windows azure and I thought there is some kind of synchronization between the locations where the cloud is available at.
So you have one abstraction but the users are served from different locations.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  You can pick which "Geo Location" you want your server to be in but I don't think they synchronise servers between the two locations.  I'm not sure they could.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking is CDN (Content Delivery Network) hosting for Windows Applications. In CDN, your content is cached on various POP's located across the continents. So, if a request is coming from India, cached copy of content stored on Indian POP is served. The same is the case for US, EU and other continent clients.

This technology is still in early phase of development and there are two types of CDN technology - PUSH & PULL. PUSH means content is immediately PUSHED to POP's when there is any change on Master server and PULL means POP servers are pulling content at regular interval from Master server and this interval is usually 12 hours to 24 hours.

If your site is database driven and frequently updated, PUSH technology CDN will be the right choice.